# Windows Azure Active Directory slow authentication on mobile devices

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a web site authenticating against Windows Azure Active Directory. It authenticates very quickly on desktop web browsers, but excruciatingly slowly on mobile devices (iOS, Android). Can anyone offer a possible explanation of why this is--and can anything be done about it? It takes minutes to authenticate on these devices which isn't a very good experience for users.

Comment: are you using OAuth for the mobile device authentication or just the web browser(normal web app) ?

Comment: To build on @astaykov's question, if you're using OAuth, what is the OAuth client and which profile are you using?  Are you using WIF or other libraries? If so, which ones? The more details you can provide, the easier it will be for us to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I'm just accessing via a web browser.

Comment: I'm using WIF - plan vanilla use of WIF to get at WAAD. No complicating factors in my approach.

Answer (score 0):

David,

Is it correct that your site is using wsfed and redirects to AAD where the client enters creds?

Do you notice where the slowdown occurs, is it before the user enters cred (if they do) or after?

Brent.

Comment: I cant' quite tell where the delay is - I only had to enter credentials the first time, after that WIF already has them via a cookie.

Comment: David are you using cookie or reference mode?  If you ware using cookie mode, try ref mode and let me know if you see a difference.

Comment: About the delay, was it quick to prompt for credentials the first time?  Was the delay after entering the credentials?