# Azure streaming is slow only inside Android app

Tags: android, performance, azure

I have started experiencing a strange case about 2-3 months ago. I have an application that streams videos from azure media services and it was all working fine. I am using **EXO Player** to play videos with **progressive download** mode. Azure provides a progressiove download link to videos inside the blob storage with media services.

Then i have realized the streaming became ridiculously slow inside the app. I am opening the same link in Chrom inside my Android Phone (Samsung Note 8) and it loads fine. I am opening the same streaming link on desktop browser and it loads fine too. Only strange thing is it loads excruciatingly slow inside the app.

I am suspecting that it could be an issue with newer android versions like 8 or 9. Because i used to use Samsung Note 2 and it was streaming fine there. I have seen similar performence issues in these questions too but none of them are related to streaming services not have an answer.

[Why Azure table storage data loading slow in my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260495/why-azure-table-storage-data-loading-slow-in-my-android-app)

[Azure web api call slow on phone but works well on android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643166/azure-web-api-call-slow-on-phone-but-works-well-on-android-emulator)

[How to speed up cloud service running in windows azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045177/how-to-speed-up-cloud-service-running-in-windows-azure)

[Windows Azure Active Directory slow authentication on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577603/windows-azure-active-directory-slow-authentication-on-mobile-devices)

Any idea would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Streaming services is not the problem because the same streaming link also works fine inside the IOS app. Only trouble is inside the android app.

**UPDATE 2**

I have converted the player to ExoPlayer and the result is still the same. I have written a small app and opened exactly the same video link and it has loaded just fine on my phone. Only and literally only problem is inside my own app. I open it in demo app, it loads fine. I switch to my original app, it loads slow and sometimes does not even start. I have tried every solution i can ever think of :(

Comment: Can you try by deleting the app data on the same devices which are slow ?

Comment: I have uninstalled the app and installed again. Nothing is changed and i have updated my question. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

Well Android web views are slow. I am facing the same issues from generations. But it depends on particular fields. Here are few code snippets which you can try. Or modify it according to your use case.

```
WebView mWebView = new WebView(this);

WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
```

Enable javascript and other modes

```
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Well, I don't thik you need it. But if needed by someone else.

```
settings.setSupportZoom(false);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

Set algorithm type in webview.
`settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);`

Try to change cache options like, Disable the cache if you have problems with your content
`settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);`

Try to use DOM storage 
`settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);`

Well this are optional, but it helps in my case

```
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
```

Here are some more. If you want to set acceleration type in webview then

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
    mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
} else {
    // if you are using older android version, disable hardware acceleration
    mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Well you can also use `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` or `"false"` in your manifest. For me **false** did the trick. You can see the proof reading of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24467920/3595386).

Comment: thanks for the advice. but i am not using webwievs. Right now i am usin EXOPlayer to play videos. I cannot modify it :/ I will try hardware acceleration but i think the problem is related to video streaming method from Azure. It is actually progressive download. But i don't know which step can be the cause :( I will update my question with additional info too.